# Refreshing tk window with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to refresh tk window when I push a button, but I have been striking out.  Help would be appreciated.  Below is what I have tried.  I would like the tk.Label line to update when I change the input box and hit refresh, but it isn't happening.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MAIN(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, borderwidth=5)
        frame.grid()
        et1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        et1.insert(0, '10')
        et1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(frame, text = et1.get()).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        refresh = tk.Button(frame, text='Refresh', command = frame.update())
        refresh.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

root=tk.Tk()
app=MAIN(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Edit:

I have also tried to use the update_idletasks(), but that didn't work either.

Answer from sc0tt's help:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MAIN(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, borderwidth=5)
        frame.grid()
        self.et1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.et1.insert(0, 10)
        self.et1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
        self.label_contents = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_contents.set(self.et1.get())
        tk.Label(frame, textvariable=self.label_contents).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        refresh = tk.Button(frame, text='Refresh', command = self.refresh_hit)
        refresh.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    def refresh_hit(self):
        self.label_contents.set(self.et1.get())

root=tk.Tk()
app=MAIN(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling update/update_idletasks won't do that for you. Here is a way of doing it using a simple lambda in the command for the button. It takes the value of the text box and alters the variable associated with the label.
import Tkinter as tk

```
class MAIN(object):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, borderwidth=5)
        frame.grid()
        et1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        et1.insert(0, 10)
        et1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
        label_contents = tk.StringVar()
        label_contents.set(et1.get())
        tk.Label(frame, textvariable=label_contents).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        refresh = tk.Button(frame, text='Refresh', command = self.refresh_clicked)
        refresh.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    #per comments:
    def refresh_clicked(event):
        #update labels here
root=tk.Tk()
app=MAIN(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit:** lambda replaced by function call.

Comment: That didn't work.  The tk.Label line remained 10.  Any other ideas?

Comment: That worked great!  Is there any way to make the refresh more general to work for the entire frame?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Could you explain further?

Comment: Well say I were to have multiple Entry slots and their corresponding Label display, is there a way to make the Refresh button refresh them all generally rather than explicitly?

Comment: Ah, in that case you would probably create a function to be called in refresh's command, and in that function you would set the labels to update.

Comment: Alright.  Thanks, I will have to look into how to do that.  Thank you for the direction to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
refresh_button = tk.Button(master=buttons_frame, width=7, text='Refresh', 
command=seeTodo)
```

To refresh windows call that windows again with a button.

Answer (score -1):

That was the only way I got this script working, otherwise I would get a error on "self" not defined. Is there other way to do add functions on the refresh_clicked?

`

```
class MAIN(object):


    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        global label_contents
        global et1
        frame = tk.Frame(master, borderwidth=5)
        frame.grid()
        et1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        et1.insert(0, 10)
        et1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
        label_contents = tk.StringVar()
        label_contents.set(et1.get())
        tk.Label(frame, textvariable=label_contents).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        refresh = tk.Button(frame, text='Refresh', command = self.refresh_clicked)
        refresh.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    #per comments:
    def refresh_clicked(event):
         global label_contents
         global et1
         label_contents.set(et1.get())

root=tk.Tk()
app=MAIN(root)
root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code correctly. Code should be formatted with indentations, not backticks (unless it is inline code). I would have edited your post, but was afraid I would alter your code because Python is indentation dependent. Also, please use correct spellings ("I" not "i" for example).